# Display memory info nicely in a gsp - better numeric display

Tags: jsp, grails, gsp

I want to display some memory info about my JVM in a GSP.

I do:

```
 <table>
 <tr><td>Total memory</td><td><%=Runtime.runtime.totalMemory()%></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Free memory</td><td><%=Runtime.runtime.freeMemory()%></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Max memory</td><td><%=Runtime.runtime.maxMemory()%></td></tr>
 <table>
```

this is ok.  It gives me values such as 504385536.  I would much rather just disply something like 504Meg or 504.3Meg.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/93001

Answer (score 0):

Divide it by `1024*1024` and add `'MB'` suffix

```
<%=Runtime.runtime.totalMemory()/(1024*1024)%>
```